# How to hide specific elements in General Settings

Tags: php, wordpress

There's any way to hide these elements?
I only want to keep "Site Title" and "Tagline" two fields in General Settings page.
[like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j4ID.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no filter to hide disable the fields, you can hide the fields using css but they are still there. you can add this to your themes function.php

```
add_action('admin_head', 'css_general_options');

function css_general_options() {
  echo '<style>
    /* Hide all Fields on the General Options page */
    .options-general-php .form-table tr {
        display:none;
    }
    /* Display the 1st and 2nd row on the General Options page */
    .options-general-php .form-table tr:nth-of-type(1),
    .options-general-php .form-table tr:nth-of-type(2){
        display:table-row;
    }</style>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that's a big help!!